# Is a one foot landing possible?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, landing, pilot-technique, wind

This video shows an aircraft touching down like a helicopter on some gravel, is this possible or is the video a fake? Are there any other videos out there?

- [Facebook video](https://www.facebook.com/bodesdoar/videos/1905472553061044)
- Similar one on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/WPyCywd4o5E?t=50s)

Comment: Is it possible to find this on YouTube?  Many of us do not have Facebook accounts.

Comment: @Simon You don't need a Facebook account to view it.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Ah, I  see.  Sorry, not familiar with the workings of the book of the face.  I didn't realise that you can bypass the login.

Comment: @Simon: Facebook is [happy to receive visits from non members](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/apr/10/facebook-admits-it-tracks-non-users-but-denies-claims-it-breaches-eu-privacy-law).

Comment: This sounds so very much like a duplicate, but I can't find another one with my limited search knowledge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have a 60 knot headwind. You have to fly an indicated airspeed of 60 knots and you can hover over the ground.

If you want you can try it out in flight sim, it makes lots of fun.

That's called a STOL.

Answer (score 8):

It's a [STOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STOL) (short takeoff and landing) plane, landing in strong headwind. It's perfectly possible.

You can find more examples on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=STOL%20landing%20wind).

Answer (score 7):

With a STOL aircraft like a Carbon Cub or Aviat Husky and brisk headwinds, it sure is.  Alaskan bush pilots have held landing competitions with these to see who can stick a landing - literally set down and hold the wheels in that spot.  The videos you reference are real.

UPDATE:  this guy officially set the world record for a fixed wing STOL aircraft landing in still air with a 10ft, 5in ground roll!

https://www.facebook.com/valdezflyin/videos/10155067657750071/